# Find the value of some floats in my animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I need to find the value of the variable "vertical" and see if it is equal to zero.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationStateController1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("vertical", Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        anim.SetFloat("horizontal", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Being new to programming doesn't mean being new to the internet. I've never used Unity but I was able to search the web for 'unity animator class" and find the relevant documentation that listed the `GetFloat` method in a matter of seconds. If you can't use a search engine effectively, which requires no programming experience, then you'll struggle as a software developer.

Comment: Hey man, when I say new, I mean I have never touched coding. Looking at that, it may seem like a no brainer to search the "unity animator class". I never would have figured that out. An explanation was all that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `GetFloat` method that is the inverse of `SetFloat`.

```
var vertical = anim.GetFloat("vertical");
```

Comment: If you have any suggestions about how the OP can better search the internet then feel free to comment on the question. Please don't muddy your fine answer with content that isn't relevant to answer the OP.

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate? When I try to compare this float to zero, I get tons of errors. How could I tell if this float is equal to zero.

Comment: What errors? Could you elaborate? Show us what you did and tell us what happened.

Comment: Ok, when I put in the phrase if (anim.GetFloat("vertical", = 0)); the equals sign shows error. It says "invalid expression term" or CS1525. I am not sure if there are any other ways to tell if this float is equal to the value zero. I am lost for words and don't know what to look up for help.